# Ubuntu Server 20.04 installing a dhcp without internet access

Tags: server, 20.04, internet, dhcp

I've just recently set up my Ubuntu Server 20.04 and now I'm trying to install a DHCP server.

But it always fails because I get

> Temporary failure resolving 'archives.ubuntu.com'

Is there any way I can set up my network without internet access?
Are there any alternatives?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could use `systemd-networkd.service` to provide you with a DHCP-server, this is already installed at your Ubuntu machine.

Open a terminal and type `networkctl` and look for your network interface name which shall host your DHCP-server, for example `eth0`, after that change directory via `cd /etc/systemd/network` and create a network-file with a name as you like, for example via `sudo nano eth0.network`.

`/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network`

```
[Match]
Name=eth0   

[Network]
DHCPServer=yes
Address=192.168.0.1/24
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes

[DHCPServer]
PoolOffset=100
PoolSize=100
```

More options are to be found in manpage `man systemd.network`.

After you have finished your config, enable `systemd-networkd.service` via:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service &&\
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service
```

And view your settings via `networkctl` again.

PS you should edit your `/etc/resolv.conf` via `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` and add some nameservers there, for example Google DNS: `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.

PPS better use `systemd-resolved.service` in combination with a `bind9` server.

Comment: Do I need to make a static IP on my Server first? And I understand the Poolsize but what exactly is the PoolOffset?

Comment: Of course you need a static IP for your DHCP-server: `Address=192.168.0.1/24`. PS don't use ifconfig and also don't use ifupdown (don't use `/etc/network/interfaces`). `systemd-networkd.service` will handle all by itself.

Comment: You may read the manpage `man systemd.network`. `PoolOffset=100` means that the first DHCP assigned IP will start at `192.168.0.100`, instead of `192.168.0.0` (which is the network address, and 192.168.0.1 is your DHCP-server addresse, so without `PoolOffset=100`, the first assignable IP address would be `192.168.0.2`).